# How to keep image and text aligned in HTML when the window is resized?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to solve the following problem: over the image of a house blueprint, I need to put "labels". So, over the kitchen, there must be a label "KITCHEN"; over the bathroom, "BATHROOM" and so on. And the labels must remain over their corresponding  rooms even if the browser window is resized. How can I guarantee that using only HTML/CSS/JS?

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="overlay.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<div class="image">
      <img src="blueprint.png" alt="" />
      <span>LABEL</span>
</div>
</html>
```

Assuming that that the kitchen position is 10% top and 40% left, `overlay.css` would look like this:

```
img {
   max-width:100%; 
   max-height:100%;
}
.image { 
   position: relative;
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
  overflow: hidden;
}  
span { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 10%; 
   left: 40%; 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

It kind of works, but resizing the window makes everything fall out of place and proportion.

Comment: Use pixels for positioning, not percentages.

Comment: Or use percentages with a fixed width for `.image`. But I would also go with pixels. And your HTML is missing a `body`-tag.

Comment: Using pixels is even worse, because that way, when the window is resized, the image is also resized (which is fine), but the label stays in the same place. I need that label and image "move together": if the image shrinks, the label must get closer to the left and top margins and vice-versa. That's why I've tried percentages.

Comment: We really need a link to all the code with image assets in order to better diagnose and help solve your problem.

Comment: @folktrash There you go:  http://fiber.quadspeedi.net/~otavio/blueprint/overlay.html

Answer (score 1):

I would the HTML5 elements give `figure` & `figcaption` a shot. They have great nesting harmony.

**From the W3C:**

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved
>   away from the main flow of the document without affecting the
>   document’s meaning.

A wonderful blog post can be found at [The figure & figcaption elements](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/).

Let your image size dictate the area, don't force it with CSS as you did with the `img { max-width:100%; max-height:100%; }`.

Your CSS could use some cleaning up as well.

Here's your code repurposed. Copy, paste and give it a shot.

```
<style type="text/css">
figure {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
}
figcaption {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
    left: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
</style>
<figure>
    <img src="bathroom.jpg" alt="Bathroom" />
    <figcaption>Bathroom</figcaption>
</figure>
```